# Как правильно обработать исключение в нескольких потоках?

Tags: c++, многопоточность, исключения

1. Можно ли запускать потоки внутри
       try{}?
2. И что делать, когда
       посылается исключение? Ждать
       завершения других потоков?
3. Есть ли в std::thread механизм для останова
       всех потоков, ну или конкретные инструменты для решения подобной
       проблемы? Или всё вручную придется делать?

   ```
   try{ 
   // стартуют потоки
      }catch(std::exception исключение)
   {
   std::cout << "...";
   }

   поток1
   {
   // при вызове ведет к неопределенному поведению.
   // может выполнится может нет
   throw std::exception(строка); 
   }

   поток2
   {
   throw std::exception(строка);
   }
   ```

---

---

А как мне в главный поток отрапортовать? о том что произошло исключение в потоке1?
Глобальными переменными?

```
    try
    { 
// стартуют потоки
    поток1;
    поток2;

    // здесь вечный цикл  
    while(true)
    {
    ... основной поток
    };

    }catch(std::exception исключение)
    {
    std::cout << "...";
    }

    поток1
    {
    try{
    ..
    throw std::exception(строка); 
    ..
    }
    catch(std::exception исключение)
    {

    }
    }

    поток2
    {
    try{
    ..
    throw std::exception(строка);
    ..
    }
    catch(std::exception исключение)
    {
    }

    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вы не должны смотреть на исключения, как на проблему, с которой нужно "бороться". Исключения -- ваш друг. Это сигнал об ошибке, которую вы должны обработать.

Функцию, реализующую логику потока, *можно* обернуть в try/catch, если это соответствует вашим целям. Можно ловить ошибки и в других местах.

Заметьте, что `try/catch` вокруг *запуска* потоков не ловит исключения, случившиеся *в потоке*. Вам нужно завести `try/catch` в самой главной функции потока. (Спасибо [[@avp](/users/232/avp)](/users/232/avp), который подметил это.)

По поводу того, что делать, когда произошло исключение в потоке, ответ такой же, как и на вопрос, что делать если вообще произошло исключение. Вы должны поймать исключение, определить, что за ошибка произошла, и отреагировать соответственно этому. Общего рецепта нету и быть не может. Может быть, надо послать центральной логике программы сигнал о том, что программу надо немедленно завершить. Может быть, надо вывести запись в лог и повторить последнюю операцию. Может быть, надо проинформировать пользователя, и переспросить правильные параметры. Может быть, ошибку можно игнорировать.

Останавливать другие потоки за вас никто не сможет, да и неправильно это -- вдруг поток держит lock или находится в середине критической операции? Если надо, остановите потоки самостоятельно. Заметьте, остановка остальных потоков в ответ на исключение очень редко бывает правильным решением.

Comment: Ну например у меня такая ситуация.
Исключение выбрасывается если не найдена или неправильная конфиг запись в xml файле.
То есть текущее исключение направлено на то чтобы пользователь сразу нашел этот xml и исправил вручную. Никаких других задач вроде задания параметра по умолчанию быть не может.

Как бы вы поступили?

Comment: @manking: Ну, рабочий поток должен отрапортовать о статусе возложенной на него задачи. При исключении он должен, соответственно, отрапортовать о неудаче с указанием неверного xml и возможно номера строки и символа, где найдена ошибка. Главный поток получит рапорт и соответственно отреагирует, ему вообще необязательно знать, что в рабочем потоке используются исключения.

Comment: @VladD, и все таки (в случае linux/pthreads), 

что произойдет, если в функции запущенной из pthread_create() возникнет исключение, которое перехватывается во внешнем к этому pthread_create **try { }**?

--

Как известно return из стартовой функции потока завершает поток. Далее в вызывающую функцию управление не передается (довольно естественно, раз стека уже нет, не так ли?). 

Будет ли такое исключение перехвачено? И если да, то как это реализуется?

--

Вопрос (автора) на самом деле интересный. Лично у меня никакого опыта работы с потоками в крестах нет, поэтому просто интересно.

Comment: @avp: насколько я понимаю, перехватить исключение из _другого_ потока нельзя. Если в потоке непойманное исключение, процесс ЕМНИП аварийно завершается.

Comment: А как мне в главный поток отрапортовать? о том что произошло исключение в потоке1?

Comment: @manking: Ну мало ли как. Пусть при старте поток получает структуру, и пишет результат в неё. Основной поток либо ждёт результат, используя join (то есть, ожидая, пока рабочий поток не завершится), либо ждёт сигнала ([condition variables](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable) (по ссылке есть пример), ну или например [вот так](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8538706/276994)).

Answer (score 4):

1) да, но это обработает только проблемы запуска, но не самого потока

2) обрабатывать. Но по месту, в нужном потоке. Каждый поток продолжит исполнение.

3) Поток должен останавливать себя сам.

Answer (score 1):

1. Можно, но исключения выкинутые из потока в месте вызова не поймаются. Это просто невозможно т.к. начиная с точки создания код выполняется параллельно. Если исключение выйдет за границы первичной функции потока, вызовется std::terminate (Cтандарт 15.5.1, 30.3.1.2/4).
2. Зависит от задачи и от политики обработки ошибок. Можно аварийно завершаться (действие по умолчанию), можно например сделать обертку над потоком, который ловит все не отловленные исключения и сигнализирует о них [упрощенный пример](http://liveworkspace.org/code/2qluhg$0). Или же
3. есть замечательные [std::future](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future), [std::packaged_task](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/packaged_task), [std::async](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async)
   [пример](http://liveworkspace.org/code/2qluhg$6)